# Joins not working in SQL Code not joining corectly strange errors occurring

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv

I have been trying to get this code working for almost six hours an I have done almost six hours worth of research.

Originally this code was to be outputted from a database through PHP to a CSV file..

All I am trying to do is have three different tables and have them all joined together by their order_ID

Every time I keep trying to do this in PHP my admin either the code comes out weird in the output is not joining correctly or is giving some sort of strange error. Any help that anyone could figure out what is going on with this would be greatly appreciated

```
SELECT
oc_order.store_url,
oc_order.order_id,
oc_order.firstname,
oc_order.lastname,
oc_order.email,
oc_order_option.order_id,
oc_order_option.name,
oc_order_option.value,
oc_order_product.order_id,
oc_order_product.name,
oc_order_product.model,
oc_order_product.quantity
FROM oc_order, oc_order_option , oc_order_product
ORDER BY oc_order.order_id,oc_order_option.order_id,oc_order_product.order_id
```

Comment: Just `FROM oc_order, oc_order_option , oc_order_product` does not join the tables by their `order_ID`. You are missing proper joins and ON clauses.

Comment: I tried this in PHP MyAdmin and it kind of half works and it keeps making one column duplicate the entries over and over for some unknown reason. FROM oc_order
INNER JOIN oc_order_product ON oc_order.order_id = oc_order_product.order_id;

Comment: You must study about joins: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/ and many more if you search.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you are missing your ON clauses.  When you are using multiple tables in a SQL query, you have your LEFT table (first table in from clause) being JOINed to the second (right table).  The "ON" clause tells how table 1 is related to table 2.  And in your case, you have a table 3.  Is this a relationship between table 1 to 3 or from table 2 to 3.  I will update the query, you will need to fill in the blanks a bit since you have not shown structures.  Also, using table aliases makes code more readable, especially if table names get long.  You'll see in a moment.

```
SELECT
      o.store_url,
      o.order_id,
      o.firstname,
      o.lastname,
      o.email,
      oOp.order_id,
      oOp.name,
      oOp.value,
      p.order_id,
      p.name,
      p.model,
      p.quantity
   FROM 
      oc_order o 
         JOIN oc_order_option oOp
            on o.order_id = oOp.order_id
         JOIN oc_order_product p
            on o.order_id = p.order_id
   ORDER BY 
      o.order_id
```

Notice the abbreviated aliases for the table names "o" for oc_orders, "oOp" for oc_order_option and "p" for oc_order_product

Again, YOU need to confirm the "ON" clauses on the left-table is associated with the right table.  I have worked with manufacturing in the past and have seen that someone orders.  Purchases a product, and that product has options, so Is there something on the order's detail line for the specific product that has an ID to the order OPTIONS table.  That is where you probably need to focus.  Again, other systems I have had, would have had a hierarchy something like

```
Order
   Customer (who ordered)
   OrderDetails (what of multiple products were ordered)
      Product ( per orderDetail, what was the product)
         ProductOption (color,size,etc)
```

See the hierarchical representation?  In this scenario, you dont go just from Order table to the Product option.  You have to get to the details to the product to the product's option.  Anyway, HTH